# `textarea` "word-wrap: break-word" not working for pre-filled text for ZenDesk Feedback Tab widget

Tags: javascript, html, css

While using the ZenDesk Feedback Tab you it appears that if you have too much text in a text area the text does not wrap correctly.

Click on the "Ask Us" tab on the upper left [**here**](https://noblesamurai.com) for an example of a ZenDesk Feedback Tab implementation.

If you have customized fields with further instructions such as this, it will, unfortunately, not wrap and simply flows beyond the right boundary:

[image]

I've fiddled and tried to force it via CSS a bit to no avail.  Other customizations work fine so I know that I've got the appropriate selector.

I was hopeful that someone might instruct me as whether I'm using the correct CSS setting to force it or if some other dynamic could be at play, particularly since this is only the initial text in a field and the actual word wrap works when ***entering*** text into the field.

Comment: Does the textarea have some overflow?

Comment: Appears to be browser-specific, as it works in FF6-8. What browser were you using?

Comment: @lukiffer Interesting.  It is indeed an issue with webkit based browsers.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks I am seeing the following for the iframe that ZenDesk inserts: "border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 90px; width: 616px;"

Comment: The overflow: hidden; is probably the cause. Try removing it or setting it to auto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is a bug in WebKit based browsers.  There is a fix already in Chrome as well as the WebKit nightly (for Safari).  IE will not support this until version 10.  It works fine in Firefox.